# react-switch-selector error in react 18 broken

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-hooks

The component will not render. I tried to start a new project and still didn't work. Is there a way to resolve the issue or do I just wait for an update from the origin repository.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.
>    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
>    at useState (react.development.js:1507:1)
>    at **WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT** (SwitchSelector.tsx:14:1)
>    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
>    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
>    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
>    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
>    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
>    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
>    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)

My Code taken from the repository (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-switch-selector)

> ```js
>     import React from "react";
>     import SwitchSelector from "react-switch-selector";
>     
>     const Toggles: React.FC = () => {
>       const options = [
>         {
>           label: <span>Foo</span>,
>           value: {
>             foo: true,
>           },
>           selectedBackgroundColor: "#0097e6",
>         },
>         {
>           label: "Bar",
>           value: "bar",
>           selectedBackgroundColor: "#fbc531",
>         },
>       ];
>     
>       const onChange = (newValue: any) => {
>         console.log(newValue);
>       };
>     
>       const initialSelectedIndex = options.findIndex(
>         ({ value }) => value === "bar"
>       );
>     
>       return (
>         <div className="your-required-wrapper" style={{ width: 100, height: 30 }}>
>           <SwitchSelector
>             onChange={onChange}
>             options={options}
>             initialSelectedIndex={initialSelectedIndex}
>             backgroundColor={"#353b48"}
>             fontColor={"#f5f6fa"}
>           />
>         </div>
>       );
>     };
>     export default Toggles;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with react-switch-selector library. they incorrectly specifies react, and react-dom as a dependency and also as pear dependency (should only define as pear dependency). until they fix it, you can use version 1.2.1